# Redirecting to a page ONLY IF INPUTS ARE FILLED in HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm new to coding in HTML. After hours of searching the internet for a way to do this, I failed and so I'm here. I want to redirect user to another page ONLY AFER USER FILLED ALL INPUTS IN THE FORM

but here if user will click submit it will redirect to next page.

```html
<form action="home.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type=text name="username">
        <label>Email or phone number</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type=text name="username">
        <label>Phone</label>
    </div>      
    <button type=submit name="submit">Sign In</button>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Side notes: Double quotes are missing in some attributes; input names are duplicated; `type="submit"` is not required for `<button>` tag (it's the default value)`; `name` attribute is optional for the button; the `<label>`s are not linked to the input tag; missing `<form>` end tag

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute. Example below:

```html
<form action="home.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type=text name="username" required>
        <label>Email or phone number</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type=text name="username" required>
        <label>Phone</label>
    </div>      
    <button type=submit name="submit">Sign In</button>
```

You can combine this attribute with other attributes, like [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern), to define a requirement in a more specific input.

At the same time, it is still necessary to check user input on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should use radio box. For example your html code:

```
<input type="radio" name="contact" id="contact_email" value="email" />
<label for="contact_email">Email</label>
```

and now, you can check if it's "checked" with php code below:

```
if(isset($_POST['contact'])) {

// code to redirect, for example header...

}
```